# Getting variables upon python Jupyter crash

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

One of the challenges I'm having is getting a stack trace or examining variables which should be in scope when an error occurs. However I am not finding this is the case. For example if a piece of code fields, I'd like to be able to see where in the loop in fails. However despite using `%debug`, I can never get any values out.

For example my code:

```
if a[field].to_list()[0] == b[field].to_list()[0]:
     result = True
```

fails, and I'd like to know what the value of `field` is. But I can never find a way to make this work using `%debug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this `try` and `except` block helps you

```py
for field in fields:
    try:
        if a[field].to_list()[0] == b[field].to_list()[0]:
             result = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(field)
        print(e)
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping that I could use %debug. Is there a way?